# Paramiko SSH - Multiple Authentication Credentials with Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
import paramiko
import time
import re
import sys
import random
import fileinput

ip_address = raw_input("Enter a valid WAP IP: ")

#Open SSHv2 connection to devices
def open_ssh_conn(ip):

try:
    #Logging into device
    session = paramiko.SSHClient()

    #AutoAddPolicy
    session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    #Passing the necessary
    session.connect(ip, username = 'myUsername', password = 'myPassword')

    #Start an interactive shell session on the switch
    connection = session.invoke_shell()

    #Commands
    connection.send("enable\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    connection.send("show version\n")
    time.sleep(1)

    #Checking command output for IOS syntax errors
    output = connection.recv(65535)

    #Checking command output for IOS Syntax errors
    if re.search(r"% Invalid input detected at", output):
        print "* There was at least one IOS syntax error on device %s" % ip
    else:
        print "\nDONE for device %s" % ip

    #Test for reading command output
    print output + "\n"

    #Closing the connection
    session.close()

except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print "* Invalid username or password. \n* Please check 
    the username/password file or the device configuration!"
    print "* Closing program...\n"

#Calling the SSH function
open_ssh_conn(ip_address)
```

How can I test multiple credential without getting kick out of the program when an exception is caught?

for example, try this new credentials:

session.connect(ip, username = 'myNewUsername', password = 'myNewPassword')

Comment: Use a try/except in a loop. Nothing says the only thing allowed in your except block is program halt.

Comment: Can you possibly illustrate that in my code...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I created a nested list with the credentials:

```
list = [['username1', 'password1'], ['username2', 'password2'], \
        ['username3', 'password3']]
```

Then, created a for loop and put my code inside:

```
for elem in list:
           my code...
           # this is the connect line:
           session.connect(ip, username = elem[0], password = elem[1])
```

That did it!!!!